# How to add WPF Behavior in the code behind

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am trying to find a way to add behavior in the code, I am able to add it successfully in XAML.

This is how I am adding the behavior in XAML to a grid, SelectedItems is a DP in the behavior and it is data bind to the view model selected items property. I am listening to the grid collection changed event and updating the DP which in turns notify the view mode of the selected items

```
/// <summary>
/// Dependency Property SelectedItems
/// </summary>
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", 
        typeof(INotifyCollectionChanged), typeof(MultiSelectBehavior), 
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

AssociatedObject.SelectedItems.CollectionChanged += GridSelectedItems_CollectionChanged;
```

```xaml
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>                
    <behaviors:MultiSelectBehavior SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems}"/>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

What I need is to create this behavior in the code behind. I am doing this in the constructor of the window that contains the grid, but it is not working, the viewmodel selected items property is not getting updated.

```
var multiSelectBehavior = new MultiSelectBehaviorSingleton();
BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.BackupsGrid, MultiSelectBehavior.SelectedItemsProperty, 
    new Binding()
    {
        Source = this.DataContext,
        Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedItems"),
        Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
    });
Interaction.GetBehaviors(this.BackupsGrid).Add(multiSelectBehavior);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var multiSelectBehavior = new MultiSelectBehavior();
BindingOperations.SetBinding(multiSelectBehavior, MultiSelectBehavior.SelectedItemsProperty, new Binding("SelectedItems"));
Interaction.GetBehaviors(this.BackupsGrid).Add(multiSelectBehavior);
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer does not appear to work in the designer, because the `OnAttached` event is never raised. An approach that works at runtime and also in the designer is using the `Attach()` method on the behavior. In this case, that would look like this:

```
var multiSelectBehavior = new MultiSelectBehavior();
BindingOperations.SetBinding(multiSelectBehavior, MultiSelectBehavior.SelectedItemsProperty, new Binding("SelectedItems"));
multiSelectBehavior.Attach(this.BackupsGrid)
```